# FixedRateBond class is giving error to price bond

Tags: python, quantlib

I wanted to price a Fixed-rate bond as below -

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import math

todaysDate = ql.Date(31, 8, 2019)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

## define available Spot rates

spotDates = [ql.Date(1,10,2019), ql.Date(1,11,2019), ql.Date(1,12,2019)]  
spotRates = [0.066682, 0.067199, 0.067502]  ### Compounded continuously

dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
interpolation = ql.Linear()
compounding = ql.Compounded
compoundingFrequency = ql.Continuous

spotCurve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayCount, calendar, interpolation, compounding, compoundingFrequency))

## Define Fixed rate bond with only one coupon payment at maturity

issueDate = todaysDate
maturityDate = ql.Date(1,11,2019)
businessConvention = ql.Following
monthEnd = False

dates = [maturityDate]
rolling_convention = ql.Following
schedule = ql.Schedule(dates, calendar, businessConvention)


dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
couponRate = .05

settlementDays = 0
faceValue = 100
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, couponRate, dayCount, businessConvention, issueDate)

bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(spotCurve)
fixedRateBond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)

fixedRateBond.NPV()
print(fixedRateBond.NPV())
```

Above implementation is failing; the cause of which I fail to understand. On line for `fixedRateBond` generation, I get below error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/QuantLib/QuantLib.py", line 15250, in __init__
    _QuantLib.FixedRateBond_swiginit(self, _QuantLib.new_FixedRateBond(*args))
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_FixedRateBond'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,bool)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date,Calendar const &,Period const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date,Calendar const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,bool)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Calendar const &,Period const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Calendar const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention,Real)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &,BusinessDayConvention)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Real,Schedule const &,std::vector< InterestRate,std::allocator< InterestRate > > const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &,DateGeneration::Rule,bool,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const,bool)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &,DateGeneration::Rule,bool,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention const)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &,DateGeneration::Rule,bool,Calendar const &,Period const &,Calendar const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &,DateGeneration::Rule,bool,Calendar const &,Period const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &,DateGeneration::Rule,bool,Calendar const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &,DateGeneration::Rule,bool)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &,DateGeneration::Rule)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &,Date const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real,Date const &)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,Real)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &,BusinessDayConvention)
    FixedRateBond::FixedRateBond(Integer,Calendar const &,Real,Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,std::vector< Rate,std::allocator< Rate > > const &,DayCounter const &
```

I was expecting the price should be -

```
print(105*math.exp(-0.067199*dayCount.yearFraction(issueDate,maturityDate)))
```

Any pointer towards the right approach will be highly appreciated.

**Modification** after David Duarte's reply:

Now, my new code-set to price the bond looks as below -

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import math

todaysDate = ql.Date(31, 8, 2019)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

spotDates = [ql.Date(1,10,2019), ql.Date(1,11,2019), ql.Date(1,12,2019)]  
spotRates = [0.066682, 0.067199, 0.067502]  ### Compounded continuously

dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
interpolation = ql.Linear()
compounding = ql.Compounded
compoundingFrequency = ql.Continuous

spotCurve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayCount, calendar, interpolation, compounding, compoundingFrequency))

issueDate = todaysDate
maturityDate = ql.Date(1,11,2019)
businessConvention = ql.Following
monthEnd = False

dates = [maturityDate]
rolling_convention = ql.Following
schedule = ql.Schedule(dates, calendar, businessConvention)
# pd.DataFrame({'date': list(schedule)})

dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
couponRate = .05

settlementDays = 0
faceValue = 100
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, calendar, faceValue, issueDate, maturityDate, ql.Period(ql.Once), [couponRate],dayCount)

bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(spotCurve)
fixedRateBond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)

fixedRateBond.NPV()
```

With this, I get error as -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/QuantLib/QuantLib.py", line 8767, in NPV
    return _QuantLib.Instrument_NPV(self)
RuntimeError: negative time (-0.0767123) given
```

Any idea why am I getting this error?

Further modification to correct negative value error:

Basically I added a `rate of 0` to correspond `today's spot rate` to define the `spotCurve`

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import math

todaysDate = ql.Date(31, 8, 2019)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

spotDates = [todaysDate, ql.Date(1,10,2019), ql.Date(1,11,2019), ql.Date(1,12,2019)]  
spotRates = [0, 0.066682, 0.067199, 0.067502]  ### Compounded continuously

dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
interpolation = ql.Linear()
compounding = ql.Compounded
compoundingFrequency = ql.Continuous

spotCurve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayCount, calendar, interpolation, compounding, compoundingFrequency))

issueDate = todaysDate
maturityDate = ql.Date(1,11,2019)
businessConvention = ql.Following
monthEnd = False

dates = [maturityDate]
rolling_convention = ql.Following
schedule = ql.Schedule(dates, calendar, businessConvention)
# pd.DataFrame({'date': list(schedule)})

dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
couponRate = .05

settlementDays = 0
faceValue = 100
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, calendar, faceValue, issueDate, maturityDate, ql.Period(ql.Once), [couponRate],dayCount)

bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(spotCurve)
fixedRateBond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)

fixedRateBond.NPV()
```

However the value I am getting is `99.68276963841888`. Shoulnt I get a value of `103.808278875`, that comes from this calculation - `105*math.exp(-0.067199*dayCount.yearFraction(issueDate,maturityDate))`

Comment: what error do you get? post the full traceback

Comment: @buran , I updated my original post with the error message.

Comment: looking at the [docs for FixedRateBond](https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instruments.html#fixedratebond) it takes either 8 or 5 arguments, and you pass 7. I didn't look into details of exact  arguments you pass. And that's exactly what the error says - `Wrong number or type of arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Try this constructor instead:

```
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, calendar, faceValue, issueDate, maturityDate, ql.Period(ql.Once), [couponRate],dayCount)
```

**UPDATE:** Also, if you want the full coupon of 5 you need to adjust the issue date for one year earlier, otherwise the coupon will be 5% times the accrual factor for that daycount.

Check the cashflows this to see what I mean:

```
for cf in fixedRateBond.cashflows():
    print(cf.date().ISO(), cf.amount())
```

Comment: Thank. Now I get error at the line of fixedRateBond.NPV() with message as RuntimeError: negative time (-0.0767123) given. How to resolve this?

Comment: Check this post for an explanation: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43885/quantlib-cds-pricing-error-negative-time-given Basically, you need to add a first date to your curve...

Comment: That helps. I added a dummy spot rate as 0 for today's date. But the value I am getting as 99.68276963841888. This is different from 105*math.exp(-0.067199*dayCount.yearFraction(issueDate,maturityDate)).

Comment: Thats help. The interest payment being considered as ('2019-11-01', 0.8082191780821812). However when I did manual calculation, I get slightly different value as - 5*dayCount.yearFraction(issueDate,maturityDate) - Any idea what this difference is attributing to?